# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when calling method from FXML

Tags: java

I am working on a fairly simple program but I can't  figure out what is wrong here. This is my Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

   private QualityList ql;
   private QualityController controller;
   private Stage primaryStage;

   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage = stage;
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/controller/QualityWindow.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Kwaliteiten V1.0");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1250, 800));
        primaryStage.show();

        ql = new QualityList();
        controller = new QualityController();
        controller.initController(ql);
        controller.setStage(primaryStage);

        ql.addObserver(controller);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is my controller class (The parts I am having trouble with):

```
private QualityList ql;
private Stage stage;
private DBClass connect;

public void initController(QualityList ql){
    this.ql=ql;
    this.connect = new DBClass();
    readData();
    initialiseTable();
}
.
.
.
@FXML
void printData(ActionEvent event){
    ql.printData();
}
```

The problem I am having is that when calling upon the method printData through the interface with an event it will cause an `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

However when calling to the same method from for example the **initController** method it will run exactly as planned.

This problem also only seems to present itself when the original **ql** object is made in the main class and passed to the controller.
If I make the **ql** object in the controller itself there are no problems but then I cannot observe the **ql** object.

Answer (score 0):

I did the initialisation of my controller wrong. this is the richt way to do it:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ql = new QualityList();
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/controller/QualityWindow.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    QualityController controller = loader.getController();
    //Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/controller/QualityWindow.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1250, 800));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Kwaliteiten V1.0");
    primaryStage.show();

    controller.initController(ql);
    ql.addObserver(controller);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```